# Three storage areas of a C program?

Tags: c, storage

I am a bit puzzled as to how the three different storage areas in a C program work. I understand that there is a stack, dynamic storage, and static storage. So far this is what I understand is going on.

- Stack - local variables and formal value parameters.
- Dynamic Storage - ?
- Static Storage - contiguous blocks of memory

I am unsure what is stored in the dynamic storage area and I don't know if what I have is right for the static storage area.

Comment: Ignoring the answers that discussion storage duration, there are several storage types.  If we also ignore the storage types as defined by the compiler/linker (the sections like .const, .data, .bss, etc.  Then within a program there are heap, global, stack.  There are sub constraints like dynamic, automatic, static.

Answer (score 2):

C has 4 storage durations: static, thread (since c11), automatic, and allocated. Dynamic storage duration is called *allocated* in C Standard terminology.

```
int a = 0;                // static storage duration
static int b = 0;         // static storage duration
_Thread_local int c = 0;  // thread storage duration

void bla(int d)  // d has automatic storage duration
{
    int e;                // automatic storage duration
    static int f;         // static storage duration
    int *p = malloc(42 * sizeof *p);  // object allocated by malloc
                                      // has allocated storage duration
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for storage durations, not areas.

- Automatic: the variable is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated on end. This is "on the stack", but stack is an implementation detail.
- Static: the storage for the variable is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Globals and `static` variables go here.
- Thread: storage for the variable is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends.
- Allocated: storage allocated on-demand with `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`, and deallocated with `free`. This is what people refer to when they say something is "on the heap". In C++, this is called dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

- Dynamic storage would be memory returned from `malloc()`.
- Static storage includes things like globals and static variables.